# WP_Query works - plugin options don't

Tags: php, wordpress

I am unable to get plugin options when loadig Wordpress outside of the directory

I have a file in root like `/customdir/mycustomfile.php` and here is my code

```
<?php

// No need for the template engine
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); 

// lload WP
include('../wp-load.php');

// load plugin info
$my_plugin_options      = get_option('my_custom_plugin_options');

print_r( $my_plugin_options ); // nothing shows ;(

$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'mycustomtype' ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'cstm_state',
            'value' => 'yes'
        )
    )

);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );


if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 

$resultHTML = '';

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    $resultHTML .= '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
endwhile;

endif;

wp_reset_postdata();

echo $resultHTML; // :) shows an unordered list of my custom post type items
```

The thing is that I can access WP_query and other Wp functions but the plugin options return nothing . its empty.

I know that it is working because when I do this in my plugin in admin:

```
$my_plugin_options      = get_option('my_custom_plugin_options');
print_r( $my_plugin_options );
```

I will get an array with the saved options from that plugin.

How to load plugins and their option outside of WordPress?

Comment: Please read this: http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/ This could solve your issue. `include('../wp-load.php');` is a bad practice, because like Otto said: `You don’t have the first clue where wp-load.php actually is`. And this can cause major headache.

Comment: Thanks, now it's working. It has to be some minor issue. wp-load.php is one level up btw. ;)